# Moving edge labels in TikZ using draw edge

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-styles

I just started using LaTeX and TikZ, and I am having trouble figuring out how to move a label above an edge. I have included my code and the resulting picture below. I would like to move the "5" labels above their corresponding edge so that there is less ambiguity. I tried the option `above` (as well as others) in the brackets following the `"5"` but the label stayed on the same side of the edge. Thanks in advance!

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, quotes}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 5cm]

\node (1) {A};
\node (2) [below left of=1] {B};
\node (3) [below right of=2] {C};
\node (4) [below right of=1] {D};

\tikzset{edge/.style = {line width = 1.0, ->}}

\draw[edge] [loop above] (1) to ["1"] (1);
\draw[edge] (1) to ["5"] (2);
\draw[edge] [bend right] (1) to ["2"] (3);
\draw[edge] [bend left] (1) to ["-4"] (4);

\draw[edge] [bend left] (2) to ["3"] (1);
\draw[edge] [loop left] (2) to ["4"] (2);
\draw[edge] (2) to ["5"] (3);
\draw[edge] [bend right] (2) to ["7"] (4);

\draw[edge] [bend right] (3) to ["8"] (1);
\draw[edge] [bend left] (3) to ["9"] (2);
\draw[edge] [loop below] (3) to ["6"] (3);
\draw[edge] (3) to ["5"] (4);

\draw[edge] (4) to ["5"] (1);
\draw[edge] [bend right] (4) to ["10"] (2);
\draw[edge] [bend left] (4) to ["11"] (3);
\draw[edge] [loop right] (4) to ["12"] (4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Welcome! Does it help if you add an apostrophe after the closing quotation marks e.g. `"5"` -> `"5"'`?

Comment: Note that the `arrows` library and the `below right/left of=` syntax are deprecated.

Comment: Also, your code is missing `\begin{document}`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you follow the quoted label with a single quotation mark, it will 'flip' to the other side of the line e.g. right to left or above to below.

I've updated your code to specify the `arrows.meta` library and the `positioning` library's syntax. I've also changed `edge` to `my edge`. `edge` is extremely confusing since it is already widely used by Ti*k*Z. At least, it certainly confused *me*. Then again, perhaps I'm just easily confused.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,quotes,positioning}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 5cm]

  \node (1) {A};
  \node (2) [below left=of 1] {B};
  \node (3) [below right=of 2] {C};
  \node (4) [below right=of 1] {D};

  \tikzset{my edge/.style = {line width = 1.0, ->}}

  \draw[my edge] [loop above] (1) to ["1"] (1);
  \draw[my edge] (1) to ["5"'] (2);
  \draw[my edge] [bend right] (1) to ["2"] (3);
  \draw[my edge] [bend left] (1) to ["-4"] (4);

  \draw[my edge] [bend left] (2) to ["3"] (1);
  \draw[my edge] [loop left] (2) to ["4"] (2);
  \draw[my edge] (2) to ["5"'] (3);
  \draw[my edge] [bend right] (2) to ["7"] (4);

  \draw[my edge] [bend right] (3)  to ["8"] (1);
  \draw[my edge] [bend left] (3) to ["9"] (2);
  \draw[my edge] [loop below] (3) to ["6"] (3);
  \draw[my edge] (3) to ["5"'] (4);

  \draw[my edge] (4) to ["5"'] (1);
  \draw[my edge] [bend right] (4) to ["10"] (2);
  \draw[my edge] [bend left] (4) to ["11"] (3);
  \draw[my edge] [loop right] (4) to ["12"] (4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Flipping fives:

[image: flipping fives]

Answer (score 1):

just small code variation of [cfr](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/39222/cfr) answer:

```
\documentclass[tikz, border=10pt]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta, positioning, quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[auto, node distance = 5cm, >=Stealth]
  \node (1) {A};
  \node (2) [below left=of 1] {B};
  \node (3) [below right=of 2] {C};
  \node (4) [below right=of 1] {D};

  \draw[line width = 1.0, ->]  
    (1) edge [loop above, "1"] (1)
    (1) edge ["5"'] (2)
    (1) edge [bend right,"2"] (3)
    (1) edge [bend left,"-4"] (4)

    (2) edge [bend left,"3"] (1)
    (2) edge [loop left,"4"] (2)
    (2) edge ["5"'] (3)
    (2) edge [bend right,"7"] (4)

    (3) edge [bend right,"8"] (1)
    (3) edge [bend left,"9"] (2)
    (3) edge [loop below,"6"] (3)
    (3) edge ["5"'] (4)

    (4) edge ["5"'] (1)
    (4) edge [bend right, "10"] (2)
    (4) edge [bend left, "11"] (3)
    (4) edge [loop right, "12"] (4);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

the result is almost the same:

[image]